# Want Java Code to Create OMR Sheeet Reader

Tags: java, swing

Can anybody give some sample code or idea on how to capture data from an image. My image is a scanned OMR sheet and I want to read the contents text input as well as marked bubbles. so that i can evaluate answers of omr sheet. i **dont want** **to use ocr tool or ocr reader which is already available.** i want to **create my own omr reader and checker.** so pls help me. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to get the support of an existing library like [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/).

In the library most of the common image processing functions are implemented and optimized, so you won't need to worry about the implementation of the functions.

Comment: +1 for `ImageJ` as a framework; still no easy task, but lots of [resources](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea.

Good luck implementing the idea, as it's hard to do optical character recognition (OCR) correctly.  Big companies like IBM have been working on OCR for decades, and the accuracy rate has been stalled in the mid to high 90 percentile for decades.

You want to do two things.

First, you want to convert a text image to text.  That's optical character recognition (OCR).  Here's a Wikipedia article on [optical character recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) to get you started.

Second, you want to determine what answers people have provided, also known as optical mark recognition (OMR).  This is a lot easier of a problem to solve.  Basically, you find the alignment marks on an OMR form.  These alignment marks will correspond to a particular `Rectangle` with an x, y origin and a width and height.  You find the other marks on the image in between the alignment marks, and calculate which answer the marks correspond to.  Here's a Wikipedia article on [optical mark recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition) to get you started.